# Change label on screen by changing drop downlist value vb.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I am developing a asp.net application using VB.NET and currently have a drop down list filled with 2 values which I have retrieved from my database. I am selecting all of the values within the table which have the column name ActorEnabled value set to true.

The code for this action is below

```
 Private Sub SelectActors()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using con As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            Dim SelectAll As String = "SELECT * FROM tblActors WHERE ActorEnabled=@EN"

            Dim myCommand As SqlCommand
            myCommand = New SqlCommand(SelectAll, con)
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@EN", True))
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
            da.SelectCommand = myCommand

            da.Fill(dt)
            da.Dispose()
        End Using

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then 'if there are more than 0 rows in datatable
            ddlActors.DataSource = dt 'drop down list gets data from data table
            ddlActors.DataTextField = "ActorName" 'text field is shown to user which gets information from column name ActorName
            ddlActors.DataValueField = "ActorID" 'value field is field on backend which allows text field to be filled in

            ddlActors.DataBind() 'bind data to source

        End If

    End Sub
```

My problem is that I want the content on the page to change in accordance with what value is selected in the drop down list i.e. if the value Sylvester Stallone is selected from the drop down list the asp Label should retrieve the relevant information about him from a database column such as his name, age and relevant movies from a table in the database.

However, I am having difficulty finding out how to retrieve this information from clicking on a value in a drop down list.

The table is called tblActors and has the following columns

```
ActorID (PK) int
ActorName varchar(50)
ActorEnabled bit
ActorAge int
```

Below is the html code I am currently working with too if this helps

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlActors" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>

    <div class="outerImages">
        <table class="tblImages">

            <tr><td><asp:Image runat="server" ID="tblActImg" /></></td></tr>
            <tr><td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblActorName">ActorName</asp:Label></td></tr>

        </table>

    </div>
```

Any help is appreciated

***TLDR;
How to change label values and retrieve data from database based on item clicked on drop down list in VB.NET***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to change your query to something like (adjust as needed):

```
"SELECT * FROM tblActors WHERE ActorEnabled=@EN AND ActorID=@AID"
```

and set the ActorID parameter the way you did with ActorEnabled, but use what NoAlias did in his response:

```
Dim intActorID As Integer = CInt(ddlActors.SelectedItem.Value)
myCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@AID", intActorID ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wire up an Event Handler for your ddlActors' SelectedIndexChanged Event:

```
Protected Sub ddlActors_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlClient.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim intActorID As Integer = CInt(ddlActors.SelectedItem.Value)

    'Use intActorID as a Parameter value for a query for the other information you need from the database.

End Sub
```